# Vue JS update computed property by user input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

My problem is to replace the value of a computed property by the input made by a user. My setup is like this:

**html**

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <ul style="margin-top: 50px">
        <ol v-for="note in notes">
            <h3 @click="setActive($index)">{{note.name}}</h3>
        </ol>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-md-9" v-show="activeNote">
    <h2 v-show="nameIsText" @click="switchNameTag()">{{activeNote.name}}</h2>
    <input class="form-control" v-show="!nameIsText" @keyup.enter="switchNameTag()" value="{{activeNote.name}}">

    <textarea name="note-text" class="form-control" rows=10>{{activeNote.text}}</textarea>
</div>
```

**js**

```
<script>
    var vm = new Vue({
        el: 'body',
        data: {
            active: {},
            nameIsText: true,
            notes: [{
                id: 1,
                name: 'Note 1',
                text: 'Text of note 1'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Note 2',
                text: 'Text of note 2'
            }, {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Note 3',
                text: 'Text of note 3'
            }, {
                id: 4,
                name: 'Note 4',
                text: 'Text of note 4'
            }, {
                id: 5,
                name: 'Note 5',
                text: 'Text of note 5'
            }]
        },
        methods: {
            setActive: function(index) {
                this.active = index;
            },
            switchNameTag: function() {
                this.nameIsText = !this.nameIsText;
            },
        },
        computed: {
            activeNote: function() {
                return this.notes[this.active];
            },
        },
    });
</script>
```

I've made a simple note-app, if you click one note, a textarea with the text and a heading 2 with the name is displayed.
Now if you click the name within the `<h2></h2>`-Tags, the heading 2 is replaced by an input field - so the user can edit ne name of the current note.

Everything works, except the fact, that when I edit the name in the input field (the name is a computed property) the name isn't updating. A second problem is, if I click another note after editing the name of one note, the name of the old note remains in the input field instead of showing the name of the newly clicked note.

I've added two pictures for better understanding:

**name as h2**
[image: Name as h2]
**name as input**
[image: Name as input]

So my (probably related) questions are, how can I edit the computed property in the input field, and display the name of a newly clicked note even if I haven't hit enter after editing the name in the input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `v-model` binding for the items you're editing. These give you the two-way binding that will actively update the underlying data items.

Also needed to use `v-if` instead of `v-show` because `activeNote` can be undefined, in which case accessing its members is an error.

```
<div class="col-md-9" v-if="activeNote">
  <h2 v-show="nameIsText" @click="switchNameTag()">{{activeNote.name}}</h2>
  <input class="form-control" v-show="!nameIsText" @keyup.enter="switchNameTag()" v-model="activeNote.name">

  <textarea name="note-text" class="form-control" rows=10 v-model="activeNote.text"></textarea>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o6v2h9hu/)

Comment: Thanks for help! That eliminates my errors in the console.log :)
But still doesn't update the name in the navigation on the left and the name in the h2-tag. Only the value of the input field is saved..

Comment: @tossel Did you run the fiddle? Does it do what you want?

Comment: oh yes thanks works like a charm .. I had a typo in there